# Как сделать сайт статичным?

Tags: html, css, html5

Хочу что бы сайт отображался на всех устройствах одинаково(отображался так как на 1905px отображается)

Comment: Можете предоставить код страницы?

Comment: sixt.venkinto.com.ua/dashboard.php

Comment: если хочешь давай сегодня попробуем адаптировать под все разрешения ! акция только сегодня

Comment: нет спасибо, мне нужно его сделать не адаптивным

Comment: Хочешь сделай... В чес суть проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого вам не нужен JS, вам нужен мета-тег вьюпорта.

```css
main {
  min-width: 1905px;
  background: #666;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1905, initial-scale=1.0">

<main></main>
```

Comment: А не подскажите как сделать чтоб и под все мониторы сайт был одинаковым?

Comment: чтоб он отображался одинаково на 1000px и на 2000px(к примеру).

Comment: @user258149 вы можете формализовать вопрос? что значит был одинаковым?

Comment: Вот у меня есть сайт который на разрешении 1920px имеет свой вид, я хочу чтоб мой сайт и на разрешении 1000px выглядел также как и на 1920px только все было меньше как при использовании вюпорта, вот только вюпорт не хочет работать на разных мониторах он работает на разных устройствах.

Comment: @user258149 так делать неправильно со всех сторон, вы не должны этого хотеть, если это только не какой-то проект современного веб-искусства.

Answer (score 0):

Задайте документу ширину в 1905px. А остальные элементы располагать можете гридами, флексамик и/или процентами. По стандарту второе даже не обязательно, поскольку браузер при маленьком экране просто покажет overflow.

Comment: http://sixt.venkinto.com.ua/dashboard.php
Ставлю в <body> ширину не помогает

Comment: @user258149, работает же..

Comment: когда открываю на ноуте то неработает, но если смотреть просто через браузер(ресайз режим) то работает))

Answer (score 0):

Если проблема состоит в том, что объекты выходят за пределы экрана, то box-sizeing должен быть border-box для всех элементов, а width замените на max-width. Но советую немного изменить структуру для экранов меньше 768px.

Comment: объекты должны уменьшатся пропорционально экрану, как при выключенном вюпорте, но оно почемуто работает только в ресайз режиме в браузере, когда я открываю на весь екран то все уходит в право.